# Bad request when calling DocuSign API for JWT user token. Consent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign API to request a JWT user token:

```
with open('docusign.pem', mode='rb') as privatefile:
    private_key_bytes = privatefile.read()
api_client = ApiClient()
oauth_host_name = 'account-d.docusign.com'
# not real, random:
client_id = 'dff16ff1-de93-477d-a73d-3774ac9932dc'
user_id = '7401f22e-ff2c-4777-9117-5932ace2e71a'
expires_in = 3600
result = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(client_id, user_id,
                                       oauth_host_name,
                                       private_key_bytes,
                                       expires_in,
                                       scopes=(OAuth.SCOPE_SIGNATURE,))
```

This returns:

```
(400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache',
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Expires': '-1', 'Server':
'Microsoft-IIS/10.0', 'X-AspNetMvc-Version': '5.2', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken':
'c1d090b7-cefd-4881-80c6-3f1c55ccc5b4', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload,
max-age=15768000', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block;
report=/client-errors/xss', 'X-DocuSign-Node': 'DA2DFE179', 'Date':
'Sun, 23 Aug 2020 15:18:46 GMT', 'Content-Length': '28'})
HTTP response body: b'{"error":"consent_required"}'
```

So how to obtain "consent". This page has two sections "Admin consent for internal applications" and "Admin consent for external applications":

[DocuSign obtaining consent](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent)

I'm not sure how to get consent in the sandbox. It already say "DS Admin" under "permission profile" for the user in DocuSign.

**Update**

I used the second technique "Admin consent for internal applications" to obtain consent with the settings:

```
admin_consent_scope=impersonation
response_type=code
scope=openid
```

And instead of the login I got the message at the DocuSign website:
"You are not an organization admin. Please contact your DocuSign Administrator."

How do I ask DocuSign to enable this feature on my developer account?

Answer (score 0):

To use admin consent you must have an organization. This requires you to register a domain name and confirm it with DNS records.
While this is the recommended approach, it's a bit more complex.
I would consider using individual consent to get you unblocked for now.
To do that, you just construct a URL like this one:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
response_type=code
&scope=YOUR_REQUESTED_SCOPES
&client_id=YOUR_INTEGRATION_KEY
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
```

And proceed to agree and just ignore the code you get back. After that you can use JWT to obtain a token.
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI

Comment: Note: `state` is not needed for this flow of granting individual consent.

Comment: Correct, I copied it over from our documentation. I'll fix it in both places.

Answer (score 0):

See this [blog post on granting consent](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent).

Note that the user being impersonated needs to consent to both the `signature` scope (if you're using the eSignature features), and the `impersonation` scope.

For individual consent, the two scopes are separated by a space which should be entered as `%20`, the encoded value.

Example:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
response_type=code
&scope=signature%20impersonation
&client_id=YOUR_INTEGRATION_KEY
```